# Make form with dynamical amount of inputs in django template

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

The crux of the problem is this:
I have a **Schema** that will later be converted to a *.csv* file. However, I need to populate this schema with data. To do this, I need columns that will have fields (Name, data type, order, etc.)
But I don't know how many **columns** the **Schema** will have
Therefore, the wording sounds like this: Create a form with a dynamic number of **columns**.

While I was writing the question, I had an idea to create a "**Scheme**" table in the database and bind a table - **"Column"** to it
Thus, when you click "add column", a new instance will appear that will already be bound to this **Schema**.
Am I thinking in the right direction or do you have another idea?
The picture below will allow you to convey the essence of the problem more accurately.
[image]
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

If I was in your position, I would utilize `HTMX`. With that, when the "add column" button would be pressed, a new row would appear.

I would also do it the other way around from what I understand of your post, I would bind the column to the scheme like this

```
class Scheme(models.Model):
...
# rows of scheme


class Column(models.Model):
    scheme = models.ForeignKey(scheme, models.CASCADE) 
...
# rows of column
```

Comment: Im quoting you - "when the "add column" button would be pressed, a new row would appear.",you mean that by clicking "add button" it will create new Column model instance binded to current Schema,right ?

Comment: But there was no "add button" in your picture.

Comment: sorry for the typo, I meant "add column"

Comment: Yes that is what I meant, you understood it correctly.

Comment: I'm not sure if I really want to get into HTMX but thank you for a good explanation about models